# Python Error Using Argparse

Tags: python, xml, csv, argparse

I made a program that converts a csv file to a xml file using argparse. First it will read the csv file as an inputfile then converts it to a xml file. Here is my code:

```
import sys, argparse
import csv
import indent
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert wordlist text files to various formats.', prog='Text Converter')
parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose',action='store_true',dest='verbose',help='Increases messages being printed to stdout')
parser.add_argument('-c','--csv',action='store_true',dest='readcsv',help='Reads CSV file and converts to XML file with same name')
parser.add_argument('-x','--xml',action='store_true',dest='toxml',help='Convert CSV to XML with different name')
parser.add_argument('-i','--inputfile',type=argparse.FileType('r'),dest='inputfile',help='Name of file to be imported',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o','--outputfile',type=argparse.FileType('w'),dest='outputfile',help='Output file name')
args = parser.parse_args()

def main(argv):
    reader = read_csv(args.inputfile)
    if args.verbose: 
        print ('Verbose Selected')
    if args.toxml:
        if args.verbose:
            print ('Convert to XML Selected')
        generate_xml(reader, args.outputfile)
    if args.readcsv:
        if args.verbose:
            print ('Reading CSV file')
    if not (args.toxml or args.readcsv):
        parser.error('No action requested')
    return 1

def read_csv(inputfile):
      return list(csv.reader(inputfile))

def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)

    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    head.set('total_holes', '238')

    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i > 0:
            x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
            if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

                collar = SubElement (current_group, 'collar',{'':', '.join((x1,y1,z1))}),
                toe = SubElement (current_group, 'toe',{'':', '.join((x2,y2,z2))})                                       
                cost = SubElement(current_group, 'cost',{'':cost})
        i+=1    
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

then on the command prompt i write, Argparse.py -i 1250_12.csv -o output.xml -x
where argparse is the program name and 1250_12.csv is csv file name and output.xml is what i want the output name to be and -x is an action converting csv to xml.
this program was working 10 min ago and now it gets an error saying:

```
x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
Value error: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: if you print row, you will see it is not a collection.

Comment: If you use a version control tool, you could see what changed since it worked ten minutes ago. That would make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but typically a return code of `1` indicates an error occured in your program.  You might want to consider returning `0` from `main` instead.  *Or*, don't return anything and just call `main()` instead of `sys.exit(main(sys.argv))`... that would be more pythonic (You don't need to pass sys.argv as an argument to main since it is already global).

Comment: you know what guys, i am the biggest idiot ever....

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are lines in your CSV that do not have exactly 7 columns. Perhaps there are some empty lines?

You could use a `try..except` to catch and handle the error:

```
def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)

    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    head.set('total_holes', '238')

    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    next(reader) # skip the first line
    for row in reader:
        try:
            x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
        except ValueError as err:
            sys.stderr.write('{e}: {r!r}'.format(e=err, r=row))
        if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
            current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})
            collar = SubElement (current_group, 'collar',{'':', '.join((x1,y1,z1))}),
            toe = SubElement (current_group, 'toe',{'':', '.join((x2,y2,z2))}) 
            cost = SubElement(current_group, 'cost',{'':cost})
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)
```

Also, if you set `reader = csv.reader(inputfile)` instead of making it a list, then your program will require less memory since `reader` will be an iterator instead of a list of rows.

Morever, to skip the first line with `next(reader)`, `reader` must be an iterator, not a list. So for the above to work, also change:

```
reader = read_csv(args.inputfile)
```

to

```
reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
```